# Tilt Control in SDL for Android NDK JNI Games

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, tilt

I am working on C++ game using android NDK and JNI system using SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer). I am done with most of the parts but i am not able to figure how to implement tilt control (tilt control as in temple run).I have googled a lot without any relevant information.
Please help me i am stuck.

Raghuvendra Kumar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: native-activity example in NDK directory shows you how to get gyro values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to use tilt control in SDL though i still don't understand how to relate x,y,z values against the screen pixel position. But at least basic operation can be performed using x,y,z values. Thanks to **aeror_** for right pointers. It's very simple. Sample test code as follow:-

```
#include "../SDL/src/core/android/SDL_android.h"

//Get Tilt values though SDL implementation
void InputHandler::HandleTitltEvt()
{

   float accelValues[3];
   Android_JNI_GetAccelerometerValues(accelValues);

   stTileValues_.x = accelValues[0];
   stTileValues_.y = accelValues[1];
   stTileValues_.z = accelValues[2];

   return ;

}

//Handle TiltValues to Move your player across the screen
void Player::HandleInput_()
{

    InputHandler::Instance()->HandleTitltEvt();

    Axis_t tiltValues = InputHandler::Instance()->getTiltValue();  
    if( (tiltValues.y > 0) && ((vPosition_.getY() + iHeight_) < (Game::Instance()->getGameHeight() - 15)))
    {

       vVelocity_.setY(iMoveSpeed + 5);


       if (tiltValues.x > 0)
       {
                vVelocity_.setX(iMoveSpeed+5);

       }
       else if (tiltValues.x < 0)
       {
          vVelocity_.setX(-(iMoveSpeed+5));

       }

    }
    else if ((tiltValues.y < 0) && ((vPosition_.getY() + iHeight_) > 0))
    {
           vVelocity_.setY(-(iMoveSpeed+5));


           if (tiltValues.x > 0)
       {
                vVelocity_.setX(iMoveSpeed+5);

       }
       else if (tiltValues.x < 0)
       {
          vVelocity_.setX(-(iMoveSpeed+5));

       }

    }
    else if (tiltValues.x > 0)
    {
           vVelocity_.setX(iMoveSpeed+5);

    }
    else if (tiltValues.x < 0)
    {
       vVelocity_.setX(-(iMoveSpeed+5));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is already included in the sample android project of SDL2. In [SDLActivity.java](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/437c4e5961e0/android-project/src/org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.java) the onSensorChanged method registers all tilt movements:

```
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        SDLActivity.onNativeAccel(event.values[0] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,
        event.values[1] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH,
        event.values[2] / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH);
      }
    }
```

Then these values can then be read in your C++ code, by calling the function Android_JNI_GetAccelerometerValues(float values[3]) in [sdl_android.c](http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/437c4e5961e0/src/core/android/SDL_android.c).

So for example your code could look like:

```
   #include "../SDL/src/core/android/SDL_android.h"
   float accelValues[3];
   Android_JNI_GetAccelerometerValues(accelValues);
```

after which accelValues will contain the accelerometer values you can use for controlling your game.

Comment: That is really helpful. Can you point some code example or tutorial like lazy foo.

Comment: I can't give you a code example, but what exactly don't you understand? It should be sufficient to create a simple loop that reads the accelerometers multiple times per second, and use those values to control your game.